# Implementing binary search to find index?

Tags: python, binary-search

So I understand conceptually how binary search works, but I always have problems with implementing it when trying to find an index in an array. For instance, for the Search Insert Position on LC, this is what I wrote:

```
def searchInsert(self, nums, target):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :type target: int
    :rtype: int
    """
    if target > nums[-1]:
        return len(nums)
    low = 0
    high = len(nums) - 1
    
    while high > low:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        if nums[mid] == target:
            return mid
        elif nums[mid] > target:
            high = mid
        else:
            low = mid + 1
    
    return low
```

It works, but I don't understand why I have to update low as mid + 1 instead of updating low as mid. Similarly, why am I updating high as mid instead of mid - 1. I've tried updating low/high as every combination of mid, mid - 1, and mid + 1 and the above is the only one that works but I have no idea why.

When implementing binary search for these kinds of problems, is there a way to reason through how you update the low/high values?

Comment: You can always use `bisect` module built into Python, or borrow the source code from github if you need to customize it. [90% of programmers can't write it correctly](https://reprog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/are-you-one-of-the-10-percent/). I'm probably one of them.

Answer (score 1):

This is personal favorite:

```py
while high >= low:
    mid = (low + high) // 2
    if nums[mid] >= target:
        high = mid - 1
    else:
        low = mid + 1
   
return low
# or return nums[low] == target for boolean
```

It has difference in the case that has same values.

for example, Let's assume the array is `[1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4]`.

with your function, `search(arr, 1)` returned `1` BUT `search(arr, 2)` returned `2`.

why does it returned most RIGHT index on the interval `1`s, and returned most LEFT index on `2`s?

As i think, the key is at `if nums[mid] >= target:`.

when it finds the target exactly same one, the range changes by `high = mid - 1`. it means `high` might not be answer because the answer we found is `mid`.  [1]

At the last step of binary search, the range is going to close to zero. and finally loop breaks by they crossed. thus, the answer must be `low` or `high`. but we know `high` is not an answer at [1].